# Change the author in Mercurial history

Tags: mercurial, updates

I have a repository in Mercurial with a couple of months of history.
In the history I can see the user in form FIRST_NAME SURNAME . My EMAIL changed in the meanwhile. Is it possible to "update" the history to this new email I have now?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19372945/2029699 and mq solution. It worked very well for me

Comment: Not without recreating all those commits which will change their hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already published your history (pushed to a remote repo which can be cloned by others), then it wouldn't be recommended.

If not published, as explained in "[Can I change the username on a mercurial changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732819/can-i-change-the-username-on-a-mercurial-changeset)", the [`--author` parameter](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--authors) of the [Convert Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) let you remap your `author` information, including the email.