# Change commit username

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the username on a mercurial changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732819/can-i-change-the-username-on-a-mercurial-changeset)

Is there a pleasant way to change a commiter *username* without breaking the revision history?

I would like to fix my username in one of my Mercurial repositories, but I cannot seem to find a way with `TortoiseHg`?

If there's no way of doing this, what is the step to change the username (even if it breaks the revision history)?

Comment: @Jon There's no "hg clone" for my mercurial installed in Windows OS

Comment: When I try to run hg convert, although the convert job finished, but looking at TortoiseHg Workbench the authors where not updated

Comment: Cloning is one of the most basic operations in DVCS. It's in *everyone's* mercurial.