# hg equivalent of git push --force origin

Tags: github, mercurial

I'm trying to overwrite a GitHub repository with my local repository, using Mercurial only.

I'm trying to follow these steps: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

> (summarized)
>   1. Clone,
>   2. In Git-Bash, execute a `git filter-branch` script that changes author info,
>   3. `git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'`

I managed to update the author info (step 2) using [hg convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757604/1052284):

> (summarized)
>   - Enable the `hgext.convert` extension,
>   - Create a text file `authors.convert.list` with lines like `old author info = new author info`,
>   - `hg convert --authors authors.convert.list .`

I'm stuck at step 3. When I execute `hg push --force` I get the following error that I can't seem to force my way around:

> abort: branch 'refs/heads/master' changed on the server, please pull and merge before pushing

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

You can't do it in Mercurial: pushed history is immutable (even if push will be successful)

**Longer answer**

In order to easy manipulate and cheat pushed history you have to

- have
- enable
- use Evolve extension (on **both** sides, which is impossible for GitHub's remotes)